# IntelliJ: limit Find in Path scope to files tracked in VCS

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control

I would like to search my whole project directory in IntelliJ but limit the scope to files tracked in VCS.

i.e. the same results I would get by performing `git grep`

I see there is a custom scope under `Find In Path -> Scope -> VCS Scopes -> Default` however this appears to exclude some files which are tracked in VCS. Is there another option or custom scope setting which can provide this?

Answer (score 2):

As I cannot currently do exactly what I want (Only search files tracked in VCS) I found a workaround by manually marking the folders I want to exclude.

i.e.

- Right click on transpiled target folder and 'Mark Directory as -> Generated Sources Root'
- Now when you 'Find in Path' the unwanted matches will be hidden under 'Usages in generated code'

Answer (score 0):

The `VCS Scopes -> Default` scope stands for the **Default** change list.
You should have also the **Changed files** scope, and other scopes for other change lists you have.

However, they only cover files with changes that are not yet committed.

There is no scope in the IDE that will show you all files committed into your repo.

But what is the use case? There is a similar request to add Search for usages in history with `git grep`. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84979

Or maybe it is something similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170031?

Comment: My use case is to exclude things like transpiled files which are in my project directory but are ignored or untracked in VCS.

Comment: What exactly are you searching for in those files? Or you just need a list of such files?

Comment: I don't want to see those items in Find results, as they add noise to matches from non-transpiled code.

Comment: In what world is it reasonable that we cannot search for just files tracked by VCS?  VSCode has been able to do it, and Vim has had that capability for decades

Comment: Agreed. It's hard to believe this seems to be impossible with IntelliJ in 2020 :/

Comment: Please upvote this Ideavim feature request
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-2342