# How do I search for checked-in files only in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I cannot find a way to limit searching to checked-in files only (a la `git grep <searchterm>`).  I really don't need a gazillion results from `node-modules` and `build` folders.

Comment: There're a lot of scoping options in the line below where you type the search terms you can play with (probably too many ). Do you specifically need to restrict search to versioned files (e.g. ignore stuff like `.env`) or just skip libraries and build artifacts?

Comment: `node_modules` and `build `folders are **excluded** from the search already. If you have this problem, please show an example.

Answer (score 1):

`node_modules` and `build` folders are **excluded** from the search already. If you have this problem, please show an example.

You also can [configure a custom scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html) which would include files you want to search and use when you use **Find in Files** action.

There is no pre-defined scope as all checked-in files. See answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42955231/2000323